# Use SCSS Syntax on a WordPress site without use of plugin

Tags: wordpress, sass

Is it possible to use SCSS syntax on a WordPress site without the use of a plugin? I was trying to upload `.scss` files to my child theme and `wp_enqueue_style` in my child theme `functions.php` but the site won't use the code.

Below is an example of a syntax I am trying to use on my WordPress site.

```
$clouds: 10;
@for $i from 0 through $clouds {
  div.cloud:nth-child(#{$i + 1}) {
    left: random(150) / 150 * 100% + 50%;
    top: random(100) / 100 * 90%;
    transform: scale(random(2) - 0.5);
    opacity: random(60) / 100;
    animation: moveclouds random(20) + 20 + s linear infinite;
  }
}

@keyframes moveclouds {
  100% {
    left: -50%;
  }
}
```

Comment: Webpack, Gulp, Grunt, Sass commands, containers, IDE auto compilers... There is a lot of options there.

Comment: The browser will not read your code. Because .scss is just a CSS Preprocessor that compile a .css which you should be using to your website. I suggest you to learn Gulp and Sass to achieve your needs. Again, you should enqueue the .css and not the .scss.